# Is there a way to ignore a file type with Webpack?

Tags: webpack

In creating my art for my website, I have some intermediate files that I want to keep in my "media" folder.

But then webpack starts complaining that it does not know what to do with those files.

Is there an easy way to say, don't worry about any files with the `.pdn` extension?

I tried these options in my webpack.config.js, and it did not help:

1. `{ test: /\.pdn?$/, loader: 'raw', exclude: /.*/}`
2. `{ test: /\.pdn?$/, exclude: /.*/}`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could add the [`ignore-loader`](https://github.com/cherrry/ignore-loader) plugin and match files to it.

**Example** (in `webpack.config.js`)

This will ignore all `.css` files.

```
module.exports = {
  // ... other configurations ...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'ignore-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

I needed it since I was requiring some `node_modules` that imported multiple font formats, but I only wanted `woff` or `woff2` formats.

**My solution:**

```
config = {
  // ... config ...
  module: [
    { test: /(\.woff|\.woff2)$/, loader: 'url?name=font/[name].[ext]&limit=10240&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
    { test: /\.ttf$/, loader: 'ignore-loader' },
    { test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'ignore-loader' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Nice, just what I needed (I was about to write this myself :) )

Comment: Hi! I used this technique but in resulting css bundle I've got something like this: url( [Object object]) for ttf/eot urls which breaks css. Do you have any hints on what to do?

Comment: @norekhov as you can see [here](https://github.com/cherrry/ignore-loader/blob/master/index.js) all this plugin does is `return '';`. If you're getting `[object Object]` then that's coming from somewhere else!

Comment: I wonder if webpack.IgnorePlugin can be used nowadays: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/#using-regular-expressions But I don't have the patience to figure out how.

Comment: @norekhov here's a somewhat minimal repro of the problem: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/tree/91a9226d433ef7341fcb7e72c52f3f20ccbac42a/webpack/css-ignore-font `npm run build` produces the `object Object` thing on `dist/main.css`. Looking for a solution now. Created an issue at: https://github.com/cherrry/ignore-loader/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

The question is not what webpack wants to do with those files, but what do you want to do with those files when you require them? Do you want their contents in Javascript, do you want require to give you the path of the files in your build or something else?

If you do not require any `.pdn` files but Webpack still tries to load them, you may be using dynamic requires. [Dynamic requires](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) can do very strange things and usually try to bundle far too much, so you should really avoid using them.

If you do want to access the files in one way, use file-loader.

In your example above, your first loader option wouldn't work simply because you're excluding everything in the exclude clause. You ask webpack to apply raw-loader to files matching 'test', but ignore files matching 'exclude', which is everything in your case. Use `{ test: /\.pdn$/, loader: 'raw' }` instead.

Comment: I just want Webpack to ignore them.  As if they did not exist.  I looked at dynamic requires and it does not look like I am doing that (string concatenation in a require statement).

Comment: As long as you don't require them, Webpack will not try to load them and ignore them. Are you sure you're always only requiring directly defined strings? No require from variables or something like that?

Comment: Nope, I don't have any of that....  I just moved the file to somewhere else (out of my dev tree) and the error went away.  (I was hoping to find a way to make it ignore it so I could leave it there... but .. ah well)